# MAX485ESA RS-485 doesn't work

Tags: rs485

I have my own PCB with MAX485ESA+ chip to use it as RS-485. I draw it similar to [UART TTL to RS485 Two-way Converter](https://www.elecrow.com/uart-ttl-to-rs485-twoway-converter-p-1545.html).

If I connect it with [ROCK PI S](https://wiki.radxa.com/RockpiS) UART3 and [Single-phase Smart Power Meter](https://www.icpdas.com/en/product/PM-3112-100), I can't transmit and receive data with 115200 baud. Instead, I get a "Reply time out!" error.

Transmit is sending (LED is blinking) but receive is not working. If I connect UART TTL to RS485 Two-way Converter with ROCK PI S and [Single-phase Smart Power Meter](https://www.icpdas.com/en/product/PM-3112-100), I can transmit and receive data with 115200 baud without any problems and with the LEDs blinking.

RX and TX are connected correctly. Any suggestions for what I did wrong?

[image: PCB layout] and [image: schematic].

**SOLVED: C3 changed to 430 pF and it works with different baud rates form 9600 - 115200 without any problem.**.

Comment: Two line RS485 is half duplex, so you must provide a changeover between TX and RX. This may cause such problems. If you create this signal derived from TX with an R/C low pass filter the function is baud rate dependent. Your driver may stay too long in TX mode and miss the answer.

Comment: First of all, why clone an auto-direction schematic as modern MCUs have handshake lines that can control the direction? Second thing is, you don't seem to have a common ground reference for the bus - where exactly is the GND_RS485 connected to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I can list some potential issues here, but it is not known which all of these mostly affect why it does not work.

- No common reference for RS-485 bus. While RS-485 uses differential signaling, it still needs common ground between devices.
- Inverter uses 5V logic levels while MCU likely is not tolerant for 5V logic levels but 3.3V.
- Enable time length may be too much and you miss the reply, as it's about 5 milliseconds, which is about 64 bytes at 115200 bit rate.